# Find min and max values of a field (column) in a feature layer

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, visualisation, feature-layer, rendering

I am using ArcGIS API for Javascript in a Nuxt application and I would like to find the max and min values of a field in a feature layer hosted on ArcGIS. How to do that? Here is the code. The values for the stops for the `visualVariables` are hard coded and I would like them to be dynamic and take the min and max values of the field.

```js
buildRenderer(fieldName) {
      this.renderer = {
        type: 'simple', // autocasts as new SimpleRenderer()
        symbol: {
          type: 'simple-line', // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
          width: '1px',
        },
        label: 'GIMM',
        visualVariables: [
          {
            type: 'color',
            valueExpression: `$feature.${fieldName}`,
            legendOptions: {
              title: '% KBA stuff',
            },
            stops: [
              {
                value: 10,
                color: '#bef264',
                label: 'minimum',
              },
              {
                value: 600000,
                color: '#881337',
                label: 'maximum',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      }
```